# Resolve Wildfly 23 Couldn't delete content ... java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, wildfly

I moved my webapp from wildfly 9 to 23, but I am getting this error message now:

```
09:27:39,244 ERROR [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1) WFLYDR0010: Couldn't delete content /Applications/Wildfly/wildfly-preview-23.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/24/77826bbb6aa397e49ef9c9c62e6aa80d5f4405: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /Applications/Wildfly/wildfly-preview-23.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/24/77826bbb6aa397e49ef9c9c62e6aa80d5f4405
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:244)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepositoryImpl.removeContent(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepositoryImpl.markAsObsolete(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:377)
    at org.jboss.as.repository.ContentRepositoryImpl.cleanObsoleteContent(ContentRepositoryImpl.java:353)
    at org.jboss.as.server.operations.CleanObsoleteContentHandler.execute(CleanObsoleteContentHandler.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1040)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:779)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:431)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.lambda$execute$1(ModelControllerImpl.java:248)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:304)
    at org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAs(SecurityIdentity.java:270)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:248)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl$LocalClient.executeInModelControllerCl(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:259)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl$LocalClient.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:157)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.lambda$executeInVm$0(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.access.InVmAccess.runInVm(InVmAccess.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.executeInVm(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:351)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.access$000(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl$1.executeOperation(ModelControllerClientFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.LocalModelControllerClient.execute(LocalModelControllerClient.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.LocalModelControllerClient.execute(LocalModelControllerClient.java:39)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.ContentRepositoryCleaner$Execution$1.execute(ContentRepositoryCleaner.java:167)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.ContentRepositoryCleaner.cleanObsoleteContent(ContentRepositoryCleaner.java:136)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.ContentRepositoryCleaner$ContentRepositoryCleanerTask.run(ContentRepositoryCleaner.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

However, immediately (like 11ms later) i get this message:

```
09:32:39,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location /Applications/Wildfly/wildfly-preview-23.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/24/77826bbb6aa397e49ef9c9c62e6aa80d5f4405/content
```

So, there is some permission issue that won't let wildfly delete the files, then it deletes the files anyway???
Not sure where the permissions settings are, any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it is a race condition as it seems that the content was to be deleted by the ContentRepositoryCleanerTask and not by being undeployed

Comment: That sounds like a quite logical explanation, how do I fix it? I am getting hundreds of these 'error' messages in the logs.

Comment: Very strange, I didn't see those kind of errors since WF11. Could you check the permissins on the files ? Also did you nrun wildfly with another account ?

Comment: The issue appears to have 'fixed it self' I have gone a couple of days now without the error messages. thanks for your help.